# Open Android's System Update page

Tags: android, android-settings

I want to open the **Settings > About > System Update** directly from my application. How can I do that?

For **Setting > About**, I can do this

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS), 0);
```

But I am looking for a way to go to system update.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it's a bit late, but here is my answer:

```
startActivityForResult(New Intent("android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS"),0)
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. I've just tried it on Pixel 2 (Android Q) and Samsung S8 (Android P) and it works like a charm.

Comment: @untosabla , glad it helped

Comment: there's just one caveat on Samsung devices: this intent starts the same system update screen as it starts on the Pixel 2 device. It doesn't start "the Samsung system update screen" so this way is not applicable on Samsung devices. I've tested it on a variety of Samsung devices with Android 6 to Android 10 and on none of the tested devices it opened the Samsung update screen. Even when one of the devices had a pending update, it wasn't visible in the screen stared by this intent. Unfortunately it varies from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

The system update activity is located on `com.google.android.gsf/.update.SystemUpdateActivity`.

You can open it by using the code below (the simplest, without error handling).

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(ComponentName
    .unflattenFromString("com.google.android.gsf/.update.SystemUpdateActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: But it is opening googles update activity not OEM specific update activity.

Comment: You didn't note that you want to get the OEM specific one in the first place, since in Nexus devices, `Settings->About->System Update` bring the Google one. In this case, I'm afraid I cannot help much. I think you can try to debug your device when it opens the specific activity to get the package and class name. Example is `com.lge.lgfotaclient/.DmcFotaUserInterface2` for some LG devices.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done works for Samsung android version 12 and 13, this code should open this page on Samsung `Intent intent3 = new Intent(); intent3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); intent3.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$SoftwareUpdateSettingLaunchActivity"); context.startActivity(intent3);` I decompiled samsung settings apk 12.0, and found this solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).